# User delta initial query : how to get the manager relationship?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I develop an incremental synchronization mechanism from an Office365 directory.
For each user, I need to know his manager.

I noticed that a call to https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/delta?$expand=manager&$deltatoken=... returns the identifier of the manager of each user for which it has changed.

**BUT** a call to https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/delta?$expand=manager does not return the identifier of initial manager.

Answer (score 1):

$expand functionality is not supported for delta query. We are working on updating the documentation.

Comment: Looks like the initial delta query has a manager ID in the "additional data" ("manager@delta" field). And I'd rather you worked on supporting $expand for initial queries...